# Find a match between two columns of two files

Tags: bash, awk

I have two files:

```
file 1:
a1 45 1/1 895
a1 65 0/1 478
a1 80 1/1 474
a2 45 0/1 145
a3 50 1/1 415
a3 32 0/1 547

file 2:
a1 45 1/1 784
a1 65 0/1 454
a1 89 1/1 354
a1 105 0/1 365
a2 45 0/1 478
a2 65 0/1 985
a3 32 0/1 658
a3 65 0/1 985
```

I want to compare both columns of file 1 with file 2 and only if both match, then I want to print the whole line in file 1.

```
output:
a1 45 1/1 895
a1 65 0/1 478
a2 45 0/1 145
a3 32 0/1 547
```

This is the solution I am thinking about in awk:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1$2];next} (($1$2 in a))' file1 file2
```

I was wondering whether there are other ways of doing this in bash.
Thanks!

Comment: You will be hard pressed to find a way to do it more succinctly that is done below with `grep`.

Comment: I just edited the question as I have more than two columns in my files and the other columns need not to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If full line needs to be matched then `grep -f` is simpler option:

```
grep -Ff file1 file2
a1 45
a1 65
a2 45
a3 32
```

**EDIT:**

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1,$2];next} (($1,$2) in a)' file1 file2
a1 45 1/1 784
a1 65 0/1 454
a2 45 0/1 478
a3 32 0/1 658
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that in the original file, I have more than 2 columns and they don't need to match, I am going to edit the question now.

Comment: Great, thanks. Would you mind explaining a little bit about your command? What I am seeing is that the first and second columns are being stored in an array, is that correct?

Comment: @anubhava glad to see you're adept at hitting moving targets `:p`

Comment: @user1945881: it is very similar to command you tried, difference is that a composite key is formed using comma in between as separator.